# Connect to remote node via xmr-core js lib

Tags: development, payment-integration, integration

Is there a possibility to use [xmr-core](https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/xmr-core) to connect to a remote node?

And handle transactions without hdwallet?

Or the library is only for using it with hdwallet?

Answer (score 0):

Considering it hasn't been update since `Sep 26, 2018` and is `195 commits behind` [mymonero](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-core-js/tree/develop) I'd go with the official version.